# Changing color of cells in row based on due date

Tags: excel, vba, date

I am using conditional formatting in Excel. I have 'Task date' in column E row 10. I have 10 rows and all 'Task dates' are in column E. I need a warning showing all cells in the same row (from B10 to H10) to change to yellow colour if 'Task date' comes 3 months before today's date. Orange colour if the 'Task Date' comes 6 months before today's date. Red colour if 'Task date' goes past  today's date. I could not do this using conditional formatting as it shows only yellow colour or no colour at all. Can this be achieved by using formulas or with VBA ? or if any alternative procedure Can you please assist...

Comment: VBA is not needed. The fact that you've tagged VBA in the first place implies that you are hoping to catch-all possible solutions without doing any research yourself. We don't like to help people who don't put in effort themselves... so perhaps edit your question to explain what you've tried already?

Comment: for 6 months    '=AND($E10>TODAY(), $E10-TODAY()<=180)'    for 3 months    '=AND($E10>TODAY(), $E10-TODAY()<=90)'    for due '= E10<=TODAY()'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to achieve is 100% pure Excel with conditional formatting. Actually I have something similar with an Excel file i Got with invoices. Just create all the conditional formatting rules you need, but remember the ORDER the conditional format applies is very important. Order your rules by what you need to check first, because it will activate the first one that meets the requirements.

Check [Manage conditional formatting rule precedence](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-conditional-formatting-rule-precedence-e09711a3-48df-4bcb-b82c-9d8b8b22463d)

Comment: Ask yourself: "does this answer still answer the question if the link breaks?" If the answer is "no" then you need to expand on what you've currently written.

Comment: As i said, the order is importan when you create conditional formatting rules, because Excel will apply the first one that meets the requirements. That's the answer. The link is just more helpful info, but the answer is what I typed. So yeah, my answer answer the question if the link breaks.

Comment: OP (seemingly) doesn't even have a formula yet so I doubt knowing that order is important really helps them

Comment: @ Foxfire And Burns And Burns - Your answer worked and now conditional formatting works perfect ! Thanks a lot and have a nice day...